# Как работает кроссплатформенность в .NET Core?

Tags: .net, dll, exe, .net-core

Как работает кроссплатформенность в .NET Core? Тут расчитано на то что разработчик на Windows скомпилирует dll и пользователи будет запускать DLL, через dotnet program.dll? Или я чего то не понимаю? (Я знаю что можно скомпилириовать exe, но по умолчанию компилируется dll, почему?)

Comment: _пользователи будут запускать DLL, через dotnet program_.

Comment: @Grundy а смысл?

Comment: @Editaw5 Из плюсов - невозможность даже попытки запуска без виртуальной машины. Так сделано в Java. Посмотрите мой ответ, он содержит список библиотек для графики, способ скомпилировать в exe штатными средствами

Comment: Да никак. .NET Core SDK пытается на это претендовать, но до реальной кроссплатформенности ему как пешком до Луны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Core пока по сути рассчитан только на серверные приложения: либо веб-бэкенд, либо сервисы. Поэтому сейчас единственным форматом файлов является dll. По этой же причине "пользователи", которые будут их запускать -- это разработчики/админы/девопсы/автоматизация. Эти "пользователи" в любом случае не запускают такие приложения по двойному клику мышкой. Плюс такой подход позволил Майкрософт все сделать самим, со стороны ОС ничего не требуется.

Возможно, когда (и если) допилят десктопный кроссплатформенный UI, придумают более дружелюбный запуск (хотя тут нужна поддержка со стороны ОС).

Comment: То есть NET Core не нужен для меня?

Comment: @Editaw5 откуда ж я знаю, что вам нужно?

Comment: игры и программы делаю

Comment: @Editaw5 используя *только* .NET Core, сделать UI приложение вы [не сможете](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server). Для создания десктопных приложений есть энное количество сторонних фреймворков/библиотек, например, GTK#. И либо вы используете целиком их, либо референсите оттуда ваши .NET Core библиотеки, в которых расположена вся логика. Насчет игр не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Исполняемый файл для .Net Core представляет собой обычную сборку для CLR и файлик, описывающий необходимые зависимости для её запуска. На текущий момент зависимости хранятся в Nuget пакетах. Подобное разделение позволяет обновлять фреймворк "модульно", без разделения на версии... Да, предполагается, что программы .Net Core стартуют так же, как и программы на Java.

Создать exe файл для Windows можно, но так как программы для .Net Core должны работать на Mac и Linux, это кощунство. Как это сделать для .Net Core 1.0 написано тут, https://habrahabr.ru/post/311520/

Так как .Net Core может работать с нативным кодом, на нем возможно написать всё что угодно. Но на текущий момент с точки зрения GUI ничего серьезного не написано. А вот Hello World написать уже можно, для этого можно использовать следующие библиотеки для графики:

**Electron.NET** - обертка для Electron, позволяет писать пользовательский интерфейс с разметной HTML
https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET

**Avalonia** - самописная сообществом библиотека, отрисовывающая пользовательский интерфейс подобно WPF, но с возможностью выбора конечного графического движка, что рождает кроссплатформенность. Из плюсов XAML, но это не точная копия WPF, не всё одинаково https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia

Comment: "программы для .Net Core должны работать на Mac и Linux, это кощунство" -- IMHO, это попытка впихнуть невпихуемое :)

Comment: @PinkTux вкусы разные, но стартовать exe файл на linux некрасиво

Comment: " стартовать exe файл на linux некрасиво" -- а какой смысл вы вкладываете в слово "кроссплатформенность"? Если таки да, до у меня для вас есть новость...

Comment: Смысл простой - у файла exe, собираемого классическим .Net на Windows есть PE заголовок. Он актуален ТОЛЬКО для Windows. Mono для совместимости с классическим .Net тоже создает подобный заголовок в исполняемом файле, но сама его не использует. Вот по какой причине нужно тащить на Mac и Linux требуемую версию Windows в заголовке программы? Exe это формат бинарников для винды, а не просто архивы, и для кроссплатформенности придется от него отказаться.


https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-pe-headers/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

Comment: "Вот по какой причине нужно тащить" -- ни по какой. Нафиг ваша виндовозность с её мегатоннами .NET никому не нужна. Учитесь пользоваться configure для начала.